# django login_required for variable urls

Tags: django, authentication, url, login-required

I am trying to write a basic website in django. I need the user (i'm still using the default one) to be able to login, logout, register, etc. I have the basic functionality set up, but I want the user to be able to visit a profile page where it will display basic information about the user. Naturally, the profile page must use the login_required decorator but the way I have it set up now is that once anybody signs in they can see any profile page.

Part of the URL file:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
    login_required(ProfilePageView.as_view())),
```

As you can see, the url should consist of "profile/" follow by the username of the user. How can I set it up so that only the user with the username following the "profile/" part of the url can see that page. With this code some user could login with any username and then just change the url and resend the get request.

Comment: The easiest is to not include the username in the url and get it in your view from `request.user`. In any case you have to write your view to fetch the profile for `request.user`, the current user.

Comment: I don't see why you want to pas username in the url pattern if those URLs won't be available to other users. It acts just the same as a /profile/ url pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. if you have created a Profile model for each user you can also access the Profile information using  profile_info=request.user.profile

```html
def login_user(request):
    username=request.POST.get('username','')
    password=request.POST.get('password','')
    user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggin/')

    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid/')



def loggin(request):
    username=None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        #profile_info=request.user.profile
        info=request.user
        return render(request,'base.html',locals())


<head>

<body>
<h5>{{info.first_name}}{{info.first_name}}</h5>
</body>
</head>
```